# Override Model File Magento 2

Tags: magento2, overrides, model, sorting

I want to override Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Catalog\Sorting\SimpleOption.php file. Please check the code below,

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Catalog\Sorting\SimpleOption" type="CompanyName\ModuleName\Model\Catalog\Sorting\SimpleOption" />
</config>
```

This is Model File,

```
<?php

namespace CompanyName\ModuleName\Model\Catalog\Sorting;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Select;

class SimpleOption extends \Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Catalog\Sorting\SimpleOption
{
     /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $label;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $sortDirection;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $secondarySortDirection;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $attributeField;

    public function __construct(
        string $label,
        string $sortDirection = null,
        string $attributeField = null,
        string $secondarySortDirection = null
    ){
        $this->secondarySortDirection = $secondarySortDirection ?? $sortDirection;
        parent::__construct(
        $label,
        $sortDirection,
        $attributeField
        );
        
    }

public function sort(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection
    ): \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection {
        
        if ($this->attributeField && $this->sortDirection) {
            $collection->getSelect()->reset(Select::ORDER);
            $collection->addAttributeToSort($this->attributeField, $this->sortDirection);
            $collection->addAttributeToSort('test_id', $this->secondarySortDirection);
        }
        return $collection;
   }

}
```

It seems not working.
Can you guys please check and let me know what is the wrong in this file or any alternate way?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Catalog\Sorting\SimpleOption` class is not created directly by `\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\FactoryInterface` so `preference` does not work.

Since you want to replace the `sort` method (a public method) in `Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Catalog\Sorting\SimpleOption` class, there are 3 approaches available:

- Use around plugin
- Override virtual types to replace the type which is assigned to `Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Catalog\Sorting\SimpleOption`. Eg:

`<virtualType name="Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Catalog\Sorting\Date\NewestTop" type="Magetu\Pagebuilder\Model\Catalog\Sorting\SimpleOption"/>`

This approach requires you to apply this change to all virtual types which assigned to `Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Catalog\Sorting\SimpleOption`.

- Create a custom composer patch to replace the core file vendor/magento/module-page-builder/Model/Catalog/Sorting/SimpleOption.php.

Because `sort` is a public method, you should use around plugin instead of `preference`.

`<Your module dir>`/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Catalog\Sorting\SimpleOption">
        <plugin name="UseCustomEntityForSorting"
                type="Magetu\PageBuilder\Plugin\UseCustomEntityForSorting"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

`<Your module dir>`/Plugin/UseCustomEntityForSorting.php

```
<?php
namespace Magetu\PageBuilder\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection;
use Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Catalog\Sorting\SimpleOption;

class UseCustomEntityForSorting
{
    /**
     * @param SimpleOption $subject
     * @param callable $proceed
     * @param Collection $collection
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function aroundSort(SimpleOption $subject, callable $proceed, Collection $collection): Collection
    {
        // Write your override for the `sort` method here
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

In above files, I've used Magetu as vendor name, PageBuilder as module name, you should replace it to your vendor name, module name.

---

More details about how `\Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Catalog\Sorting\SimpleOption` class is created: when `Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Catalog\Sorting` class (Sorting of Catalog Widget Products) is initiating, it initiates `sortInstances` via `sortClasses` argument:

```
/**
 * @param Sorting\Factory $factory
 * @param array $sortClasses
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
 */
public function __construct(
    Sorting\Factory $factory,
    array $sortClasses
) {
    $this->sortClasses = $sortClasses;
    $this->factory = $factory;
    foreach ($this->sortClasses as $key => $className) {
        $this->sortInstances[$key] = $this->factory->create($className);
    }
}
```

which is passed in `<Magento_PageBuilder module dir>/etc/di.xml`:

```
<type name="Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Catalog\Sorting">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="sortClasses" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="position" xsi:type="string">Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Catalog\Sorting\Position\Ascending</item>
            <item name="position_by_sku" xsi:type="string">Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Catalog\Sorting\PositionBySku</item>
            <item name="date_newest_top" xsi:type="string">Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Catalog\Sorting\Date\NewestTop</item>
            <item name="date_oldest_top" xsi:type="string">Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Catalog\Sorting\Date\OldestTop</item>
            <item name="name_ascending" xsi:type="string">Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Catalog\Sorting\Name\Ascending</item>
            <item name="name_descending" xsi:type="string">Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Catalog\Sorting\Name\Descending</item>
            <item name="sku_ascending" xsi:type="string">Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Catalog\Sorting\Sku\Ascending</item>
            <item name="sku_descending" xsi:type="string">Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Catalog\Sorting\Sku\Descending</item>
            <item name="low_stock_first" xsi:type="string">Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Catalog\Sorting\Stock\Ascending</item>
            <item name="high_stock_first" xsi:type="string">Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Catalog\Sorting\Stock\Descending</item>
            <item name="price_high_to_low" xsi:type="string">Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Catalog\Sorting\Price\Descending</item>
            <item name="price_low_to_high" xsi:type="string">Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Catalog\Sorting\Price\Ascending</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

For example, class `date_newest_top` is assigned to `Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Catalog\Sorting\Date\NewestTop` class, whenever factory creates that class, it calls `Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Catalog\Sorting\SimpleOption` instead as the config defined in `<Magento_PageBuilder module dir>/etc/di.xml`:

```
<virtualType name="Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Catalog\Sorting\Date\NewestTop" type="Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Catalog\Sorting\SimpleOption">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Newest products first</argument>
        <argument name="sortDirection" xsi:type="const">\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::SQL_DESC</argument>
        <argument name="attributeField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Here `Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Catalog\Sorting\SimpleOption` is not created directly from `factory` so `preference` does not work.

Comment: I am not getting this $this->secondarySortDirection value dynamically in plugin file,
$collection->addAttributeToSort('row_id', $this->secondarySortDirection);

Comment: `$this` is the variable for the plugin class, not for the original class, to call the original class, you should use `$subject`. But `secondarySortDirection`, `sortDirection`, and `attributeField` are private properties so you can't call them from the plugin class. And these properties are passing via di.xml so you can't get them in the plugin. So you should go with another approach, please let me if you have any questions.

Comment: Yes, I used virtual type and it works for me. Thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome. Cheers!

Comment: Can you please look into this and guide me? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/365303/discount-calculation-issue-magento-2

Comment: @SunnyRahevar I'm not available for this issue at this time, hope you can resolve it soon.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code as your Model File

```
<?php
    
    namespace CompanyName\ModuleName\Model\Catalog\Sorting;
    use Magento\Framework\DB\Select;
    
    class SimpleOption extends \Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Catalog\Sorting\SimpleOption
    {
         /**
         * @var string
         */
        private $label;
    
        /**
         * @var string
         */
        private $sortDirection;
    
        /**
         * @var string
         */
        private $secondarySortDirection;
    
        /**
         * @var string
         */
        private $attributeField;
    
        public function __construct(
            string $label,
            string $sortDirection = null,
            string $attributeField = null,
            string $secondarySortDirection = 'asc'
        ){
            $this->secondarySortDirection = $secondarySortDirection;
            parent::__construct(
            $label,
            $sortDirection,
            $attributeField
            );
            
        }
    
    public function sort(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection
        ): \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection {
            
            if ($this->attributeField && $this->sortDirection) {
                $collection->getSelect()->reset(Select::ORDER);
                $collection->addAttributeToSort($this->attributeField, $this->sortDirection);
                $collection->addAttributeToSort('test_id', $this->secondarySortDirection);
            }
            return $collection;
       }
    
    }
```